# Correct way for long running background task on ASP.NET Core, for CPU bound and I/O bound

Tags: .net, async-await, background, task-parallel-library, threadpool

In my .NET7 ASP.NET server I use this code to do some background processing for the lifetime of the application.

```
_ = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        { 
            if (isDataAvalibale) await DoDBBoundProcessing();
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write("", $"Background error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
 }
```

Then I have another one for CPUBoundProcessing. The Processing functions must repeat continuously.

The first serializes data to a DB from a ConcurrentQueue and the other does some processing on a memory object.

The Task.Run works, never had any problem, but I understand it's not the best way to deal with background processing.
I've read this from David Fowler:
https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread

that suggest to use:

```
    var thread = new Thread(ProcessQueue) 
    {
        // This is important as it allows the process to exit while this thread is running
        IsBackground = true
    };
    thread.Start();
```

or

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessQueue, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

But I don't understand which one is more suitable to my use case.
Then there is the "Background tasks with hosted services" option.

I'd like to keep things as simple as possibile, and in terms of reliability my current Task.Run is ok:

- it's ok if the server stops the background processes stop
- it's ok if for some reason one Processing creates an exception and restarts

I just want to manage correctly the threads/task resources.

What is the correct approach for my use cases?
Should it be different for CPU bound an I/O bound oeprations?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should look at background workers instead: https://blog.elmah.io/async-processing-of-long-running-tasks-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @ThomasArdal BackgroundWorker is another option then, along with "Background tasks with hosted services", but what I can't find anywhere is an explanation on why one method is better than another, what are the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Those are the same thing. But you're right, it would be nice with an article explaining all the different options. Tasks, background worker, Hangfire, Functions, etc. And comparing them to each other. I haven't seen an article like that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the both approaches because the thread pool thread will execute your code until await task.delay code than will return back to the pool.After 10ms another thread in thread pool will continue to execute where it left.
But you should handle asp.net restart events so use [Hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) put your code (start your task. but dont return that task) in StartAsync and check cancellation token in your loop.